# MacBook Air - with Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit wireless card is not recognized, mouse pad do not work properly

Tags: wireless, 14.04, mouse, macbook

Bought brand new Macbook Air and then installed Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit successfully but major hardwares are not compatible such as WiFi card and mouse pad is not working smoothly like in OSX it does. How to fix the WiFi cause i have no other network interface on this MacBook Air.

Optiona: Here is how i installed:

**Step 1:** on Mac OSX 10.9.2 Open disk utility i resize 80GB for mac and 40GB as unallocated

**Step 2:** optional: refind-bin-0.8.0.zip, basically its a GUI bootable screen
if i do not install it there is no big deal cause Ubuntu has itself TUI GRUB menu. was confused so installed it anyway.

```
$ ls
COPYING.txt LICENSE.txt README.txt  docs        install.sh  mkrlconf.sh refind
CREDITS.txt NEWS.txt    banners     fonts       keys        mvrefind.sh
$ ./install.sh 
Not running as root; attempting to elevate privileges via sudo....
Password:
Installing rEFInd on OS X....
Installing rEFInd to the partition mounted at //
Copied rEFInd binary files

Copying sample configuration file as refind.conf; edit this file to configure
rEFInd.


WARNING: If you have an Advanced Format disk, *DO NOT* attempt to check the
bless status with 'bless --info', since this is known to cause disk corruption
on some systems!!


Installation has completed successfully.
```

**Step 3:** Download Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit ISO for bootable USB stick

```
$ hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.img ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
Reading Driver Descriptor Map (DDM : 0)…
Reading Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64           (Apple_ISO : 1)…
Reading Apple (Apple_partition_map : 2)…
Reading Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64           (Apple_ISO : 3)…
..................................................................................................................
Reading EFI (Apple_HFS : 4)…
...................................................................................................................
Reading Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64           (Apple_ISO : 5)…
...................................................................................................................
Elapsed Time:  8.123s
Speed: 118.7Mbytes/sec
Savings: 0.0%
created: /Users/sun/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.img.dmg

$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            80.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *120.0 GB   disk1
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 UUI                     120.0 GB   disk1s1

$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1
Unmount of all volumes on disk1 was successful

$ sudo dd if=ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.img.dmg of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
Password:
964+0 records in
964+0 records out
1010827264 bytes transferred in 24.643578 secs (41017877 bytes/sec)
```

NOTE: wired popup came out , press IGNORE

[image]

```
$ diskutil eject /dev/disk1
Disk /dev/disk1 ejected
```

**Step 4:** reboot and boot with usb stick, do the partition
where i selected "something else" to make the Ubuntu partition and completed the ubuntu setup, by selecting the EFI

After booting to Ubuntu cant make WiFi working and there is no other way to go to internet, switched back to Mac OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bought Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter - which worked with 14.04

[image]

Here is the devices details:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0290 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:828f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0461:4d65 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 1570
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
04:00.0 SATA controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 010b (rev 14)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] (rev 03)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] (rev 03)
06:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] (rev 03)
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] (rev 03)
06:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] (rev 03)
06:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] (rev 03)
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] (rev 03)
08:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge]
09:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge]
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
```

Answer (score 0):

> 03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

A [poster](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205494) with a macbook pro retina 13" (late 2013) with a BCM4360 NIC had success with posts [4-6](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2159851)

[bcm4360](/questions/tagged/bcm4360)

Comment: [BCM43xx Driver on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)