# No Wireless When Install 14.04 on Macbook Pro

Tags: wireless, 14.04, macbook-pro

So I'm attempting to dual-boot OS X 10.8.5 (native OS) and Ubuntu 14.04.
I installed Ubuntu (hooray!) but upon booting into Ubuntu I discovered I have no network connection from the OS.  I'm very new to Linux.

I've noticed some [similar posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462759/macbook-air-with-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-wireless-card-is-not-recognized-mouse-pa), however the only "solution" I've seen so far is to screw the wireless connection and buy a USB-ethernet adapter.  If I was using this computer at home that'd be fine.  But this is in an office and it's WiFi only.

Is there anyway to get the wireless adapter to work?

Mac Book Pro, Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012
CPU 2.5 Ghz Intel Core i5
Memory 8GB

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux ______-MacBookPro 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### arch #####

x86_64

##### lspci #####

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16a3] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16a3]
02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 21)

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:010f]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:0259 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 05ac:828c Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2512 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8510 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1058:0748 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport 1TB USB 3.0
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:8110  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:2811  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #####

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

No way to aquire root rights found.

##### iwlist channel #####

##### lsmod #####

b43                   387371  0 
mac80211              626489  1 b43
cfg80211              484040  2 b43,mac80211
ssb                    62379  1 b43
bcma                   52096  1 b43

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     BED87D210887FFC71A4BDE0
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev1Dcl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev18cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev17cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev11cl*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev10*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0F*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0D*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0C*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0B*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0A*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev09*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev07*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev06*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev05*
depends:        bcma,ssb,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        :47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     3DE188310F77C566C2E8CB3
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004350sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004329sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004325sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004324sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004322sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004321sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004320sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004319sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014A4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004315sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004312sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004311sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004307sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004306sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004301sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        :47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     E41B811D88783DD5BC38565
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004727sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004365sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004359sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004358sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004357sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004353sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004331sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004313sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00000576sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        :47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### modules #####

lp
rtc

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

##### dmesg #####

[    5.075877] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4331, rev 0x02 and package 0x09
[    5.075904] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x25, class 0x0)
[    5.075926] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x1D, class 0x0)
[    5.075969] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x13, class 0x0)
[    5.136742] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
[    5.489707] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4331 WLAN found (core revision 29)
[    5.490133] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 9, Type 7 (HT), Revision 1
[    5.490749] b43 bcma0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    5.490750] b43 bcma0:0: Falling back to user helper
[    5.496210] b43 bcma0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    5.496211] b43 bcma0:0: Falling back to user helper
[    5.496741] b43 bcma0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    5.496741] b43 bcma0:0: Falling back to user helper
[    5.497163] b43 bcma0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    5.497164] b43 bcma0:0: Falling back to user helper
[    5.497850] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found
[    5.497851] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found
[    5.497852] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Thanks Wild Man.  Output from the script is added to the original post.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot if it does not connect post a new file from the script.

No internet:

Download the [b43updated.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/19e7y7w6ndozdzq/b43_updated.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAEELVjeW3iSm3d0ScTg17BSplJ01qhPGCkhav5o9EYiJA&expiry=1400713892) file to a usb flash drive then drag and drop the file to your ubuntu desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here.

Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43
sudo modprobe -rv b43 
sudo modprobe -v b43
```

if it does not come on reboot.

Comment: apt-get is not work for me, but manual download  b43updated.zip is worked! Thank' a lot.

Comment: I can confirm that this also works for the Broadcom 4331 on the Macbook Pro Late 2011. Thanks @WildMan!

Comment: Worked perfectly on my ancient 17-inch iMac (Intel Core Duo). Thanks!

Comment: Does work for 12.04 LTS (however, I needed to use `cd Desktop > sudo unzip b43_updated.zip -d /lib/firmware` followed by the other commands (NO REBOOT REQUIRED).  unzipping to /lib/firmware/b43 would result in .../b43/b43, and then the other commands don't work.  Super happy this worked: 3 days working on this thing.  It wasn't taking to a wired network, either, but it did for a few minutes so this is useful: https://staff.washington.edu/curreri/getting-ubuntu-12-04-and-wireless-working-on-a-powerbook-g4/

Comment: Can you use Macbook Pro's firmware in Macbook Air 2013-mid? I have a thread about it here http://askubuntu.com/q/779215/25388

Comment: The second line of code must be `sudo cp Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43` because after extract, the created folder is named b43.

Comment: I had the same problem and actually didn't have to install anything directly: the cdrom has the drivers, they just need to be activated: go to Settings (top right corner) then Updates -> Additional drivers -> activate your broadcom wifi driver there.

Comment: Great answer!  This worked perfectly.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Keep in mind, you need an internet connection for apt-get to work.  apt-get will fail unless you have the ethernet cable plugged in.

Comment: @AdamTegen, there are directions for installing the firmware without an internet connection in the answer, it specifically says No internet do the following, so not sure why this comment is necessary, and on an answer 3 years old, Personally there are already to many comments and it could have used a clean up.

Comment: This solution worked on my late 2012 iMac!

Comment: Thanks! After confirming same wifi chipset on my early 2009 iMac 24" I followed the instructions and I had wifi without a reboot. Did this on 18.04 LTS.

Comment: still works in 2021.. thumbs up!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue on macMini

```
>lspci -nn
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
```

and this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

and then a reboot

Answer (score 0):

You will need to USB tether by phone or connect a network cable into your computer  in order to install software over the internet.

Try using the software updates applette on the settings control center.  Go to the drivers tab and select the proprietary device drivers for the Broadcom wireless.

That worked for me.