# Driver for asus wireless PC card WL-100GE

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I have bought an Asus wireless LAN PC Card WL-100GE model, and I am using lubuntu on my system. While I have no cable connection, currently I cannot access the internet and update my laptop.

Device: Broad Range Wireless Card Bus Adaptor - Asus - WL-100GE

I searched the web and couldn't find any adequate driver for it. Is there any solution for it?

My `sudo lshw -C network` output is:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:02:03.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:02:3f:ba:55:c8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=half latency=128 link=no maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:e0200800-e02008ff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=64
       resources: irq:21 memory:38000000-38001fff
----:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Wireless When Install 14.04 on Macbook Pro](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470153/no-wireless-when-install-14-04-on-macbook-pro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing b43 drivers described in the [ubuntu web site documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx).