# 14.04 - Proprietary wireless card driver on MBP installs on USB, not on HD

Tags: 14.04, boot, wireless, drivers, hard-drive

I wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my MacBook Pro, and so I tried running it off a USB key to see if there were any issues. The one proprietary driver needed, Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source, installs perfectly when booting from the USB key. I went ahead and installed in on my HD.

When I boot up from the hard drive, I try to use this proprietary driver, and when I clikc the "Apply Changes" button in the Additional Drivers tab of the Software & Updates Settings page, it just reverts to the original position: "Do not use the device".

**Why is this happening? How can I apply the proprietary driver when booting from my hard drive**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it was done on a different MacBook Pro model the answer [provided here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470153/no-wireless-when-install-14-04-on-macbook-pro#_=_) works for 14.04 on the MacBook Pro 13" Late 2011.

> Download the [b43updated.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/19e7y7w6ndozdzq/b43_updated.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAEELVjeW3iSm3d0ScTg17BSplJ01qhPGCkhav5o9EYiJA&expiry=1400713892) file to a usb flash drive then drag and drop the file > to your ubuntu desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here.
>
> Open a terminal and do:
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
> sudo cp Desktop/b43_updated.zip/*  /lib/firmware/b43
> sudo modprobe -rv b43 
> sudo modprobe -v b43
> ```
>
> if it does not come on reboot.