# No Wi-Fi on MacBookPro7,1

Tags: wireless, 15.04, macbook-pro

So I managed to successfully install Ubuntu and get everything working except wireless.

I do not have an Internet connection, but I can retrieve files from the Internet via use of my OS X partition.

I used b43updated.zip from this thread: [No Wireless When Install 14.04 on Macbook Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470153/no-wireless-when-install-14-04-on-macbook-pro). I can see "Connect to hidden connection" and can toggle wireless, but no networks appear in the list.

Output of lspci -nn | grep 0280:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
```

I'm also using Ubuntu MATE at this point, not Ubuntu.

I've also managed to get the Wi-Fi networks to show in the network list, but not to connect.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of the wireless card from the terminal: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check here: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395) The correct driver for your 14e4:432b device is bcmwl-kernel-source. You can retrieve it and its dependency dkms from the install DVD or USB using this method. Navigate to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag and drop the deb file to your desktop. Now navigate to pool > main > d > dkms and drag and drop dkms to your desktop. Now install both with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: I now have no CD access (my SuperDrive is broken and my external drive broke), but I now have access to Ethernet. What packages should I install?EDIT: nevermind it was in the thread you posted. thanks so much

Comment: May I assume it's all working now? If my answer has been helpful, please accept it.

Comment: There's still a problem. I now see "Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network" and "Create New Wi-Fi Network", but no networks appear in the list, nor can I manually connect to one by entering the SSID and Password. EDIT: suddenly it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Get internet with alternative way such as ethernet or usb modem
2. Go into the Ubuntu dash and look up Drivers
3. Click on "Additional drivers"
4. let it load
5. Select the one that says broadcom and on it and install
6. Reboot and you will have wifi

Of course this will only work, if you can arrange alternate internet connection for few minutes.